# Any way to make Vault auto check in files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sourcegear-vault

Does anyone know if there is a way to make Vault, or the users of Vault to automatically check in their checked out files at a certain time of day (i.e. after office hours).

I know there are obvious drawbacks to implementing this so if anyone has any ideas to bring about the desired result (checked in files), please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really possibly think of any benefit automatic commits could bring.

If I have some unfinished work on my local computer, I can either have two choices, or a single one depending on this factor:

> Am I using distrubuted versioning or centralized versioning?

In the first scenario I can committ locally without pushing to the central repository, thus gaining the benefits of version control without forcing other people to deal with my unfinished or possibly broken code.

If it's centralized versioning, you suck it up and keep it locally for the next day, hoping your HDD doesn't fail overnight.

It's really simple as that. Then to just answer your question, no, I don't recall such functionality in vault (or any other versioning software) and I think that would be a terrible idea.

Comment: In centralised versioning, if I am ill for a few days and left something checked out, what should others do?

Comment: There's RDP, VPN, etc. If your code wasn't complete, it's not ready to be integrated to the repository no matter what. If it was complete and you forgot to commit it, that's a disciplinary matter, and should be handled as that, and not as a thecnical issue.