# Emulation of the work of programmer and automatic committing to TFS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, powershell, tfs

Is it possible to write a script for VS or TFS in order to simulate the work of programmer? For example, it would make minor changes in js file (swap two function) an commit it to TFS on schedule.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a recommend way to use automatic check-in/commit in a mature source control system.

If files are going to commit automatically, some negative issues have also followed. Who is going to add the comment, what comment should be add, Who is going to associate it with related work items?  These things are really important features of TFS as an ALM tool to enable traceability and visibility.These will make source control history more detailed and easy to management.

Moreover, "**how to guarantee the quality of the code available in the server?**" is another serious problem. Even though it's just making minor changes, which may also has a huge impact. When another developer gets the latest version he may receive code that is not working, because of the  work checked in automatically by script, and so on.

The answer in this question (even not about TFS) have some useful facts for your reference. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397918/any-way-to-make-vault-auto-check-in-files)

If you really need this feature, to achieve your requirement, you could create a **VS add-in** project, and then use TFS API to check in the files. About how to use TFS API to check in files, please refer to this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/).